# SQL - INSERT INTO multiple columns from multiple selections

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, pivot-table

I have a MariaDB database.

Inside that DB, I have the following table, *table1*:

```
|     id       |     timestamp     |  unit |  detector  |    value    |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
     UUID()         2020-12-02          1        1             0.1
     UUID2()        2020-12-02          1        2             0.2
     UUID3()        2020-12-02          2        1             0.3
     UUID4()        2020-12-02          2        2             0.4
     UUID5()        2020-12-03          1        1             0.5
     UUID6()        2020-12-03          1        2             0.6
     UUID7()        2020-12-03          2        1             0.7
     UUID8()        2020-12-03          2        2             0.8
```

I have been asked to map the data to this new table, *table2*

```
 |     id       |     timestamp     |  detector 11   |   detector 12   |  detector 21  |  detector 22 |
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       UUI9()         2020-12-02            0.1              0.2             0.3             0.4
       UUID10()        2020-12-03            0.5              0.6             0.7             0.8
```

The only difference from this situation is that I have 100 detector and unit combinations and 36 million rows. I have written code that can get the desired value for 1 detector but I can't figure out a way of doing multiple rows -> columns at the same time. No way I'm doing this manually, it would take weeks.

```
INSERT INTO table2
(id, timestamp, detector11)
SELECT UUID(), t1.timestamp, t1.value FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.unit='1' AND t1.detector='1'
ORDER BY timestamp ;
```

This successfully translates the data from table1 where (detector=1, unit=1) to the column (detector11) with a good timestamp. However, now I have all the other columns except for id, timestamp, and detector11 to NULL.

Ideally, someone could help me to code something like that:

```
INSERT INTO table2
(id, timestamp, detector11, detector12, detector21, detector22)
SELECT UUID(), t1.timestamp, 
VALUES(t1.value FROM table1 t1
       WHERE t1.unit='1' AND t1.detector='1'
       ORDER BY timestamp,

       t1.value FROM table1 t1
       WHERE t1.unit='1' AND t1.detector='2'
       ORDER BY timestamp,

       t1.value FROM table1 t1
       WHERE t1.unit='2' AND t1.detector='1'
       ORDER BY timestamp,

       t1.value FROM table1 t1
       WHERE t1.unit='2' AND t1.detector='2'
       ORDER BY timestamp) ;
```

Which would fill all the columns at the same time.

Comment: How does `UID2()` end up on `2020-12-03` when there is no data for that id on that date?

Comment: Sorry, this is a misunderstanding, UUID() means a randomly generated id. I will change that. All UUID are different, they are the primary keys.

Comment: Why do you want to de-normalize data? Why save to table and not just use a query?

Comment: because, I tried to explain query's to my bosses, no chance they want a .csv that has that exact structure, so I'll build that table and I have a table to csv converter I made in python with sqlalchemy

Comment: Should be able to export query to CSV.

Comment: Didn't know I could do that. I started SQL this month to help them, but now, I'm in charge of this thing apparently. I'll test your answers tomorrow, thanks all for your time.

Comment: See the [pivot-table] tag.

Comment: For MariaDB, see See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56670844/1766831

Answer (score 1):

You can only join the separate Tables.

The problem is to join the values, there you have to see if your `ON` statement for the join is so valid

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table2 (id varchar(20), `timestamp` TIMESTAMP, detector11 DECIMAL(4,2), detector12 DECIMAL(4,2)
> , detector21 DECIMAL(4,2), detector22 DECIMAL(4,2))
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (`timestamp`TIMESTAMP, value DECIMAL(4,2), unit INT,detector INT)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table2
> (id, timestamp, detector11, detector12, detector21, detector22)
> SELECT UUID(),t1a.timestamp, t1a.detector11,t1b.detector12,t1c.detector21,t1d.detector22
> FROM
> (SELECT
> t1.timestamp, t1.value as detector11 FROM table1 t1
> WHERE t1.unit='1' AND t1.detector='1'
> ORDER BY timestamp ) t1a
> JOIN
>   (SELECT t1.timestamp, t1.value AS detector12 FROM table1 t1
>        WHERE t1.unit='1' AND t1.detector='2'
>        ORDER BY timestamp) t1b
>        ON t1a.timestamp = t1b.timestamp
> JOIN       
>   (SELECT t1.timestamp,t1.value AS detector21 FROM table1 t1
>        WHERE t1.unit='2' AND t1.detector='1'
>        ORDER BY timestamp) t1c
>        ON t1a.timestamp = t1c.timestamp
> JOIN
>   (SELECT t1.timestamp,t1.value AS detector22 FROM table1 t1
>        WHERE t1.unit='2' AND t1.detector='2'
>        ORDER BY timestamp) t1d
>   ON t1a.timestamp = t1d.timestamp
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=e1265cf3676057832f0e2ee4e3655b52)*

We can try another approach, but this i also never used with hundrds of columns so you have to test it yourself

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1
>     (`id` varchar(7), `timestamp` varchar(10), `unit` int, `detector` int, `value` DECIMAL(10,1))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO table1
>     (`id`, `timestamp`, `unit`, `detector`, `value`)
> VALUES
>     ('UUID()', '2020-12-02', 1, 1, 0.1),
>     ('UUID2()', '2020-12-02', 1, 2, 0.2),
>     ('UUID3()', '2020-12-02', 2, 1, 0.3),
>     ('UUID4()', '2020-12-02', 2, 2, 0.4),
>     ('UUID5()', '2020-12-03', 1, 1, 0.5),
>     ('UUID6()', '2020-12-03', 1, 2, 0.6),
>     ('UUID7()', '2020-12-03', 2, 1, 0.7),
>     ('UUID8()', '2020-12-03', 2, 2, 0.8)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=4294967295;
> SET @sql = NULL;
> SELECT
>   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
>     CONCAT(
>       "MAX(CASE WHEN `unit` = ",
>       `unit`,
>       " AND `detector` = ",`detector`," THEN `value` ELSE 0  END) AS 'Detector",
>       
>       `unit`,`detector`,"'"
>     )
>   ) INTO @sql
>   
>   FROM `table1`;
>
> SET @sql = CONCAT("SELECT uuid(),`timestamp`, ",@sql," from table1
> group by `timestamp`");
>
> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
> EXECUTE stmt;
> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> uuid()                               | timestamp  | Detector11 | Detector12 | Detector21 | Detector22
> :----------------------------------- | :--------- | ---------: | ---------: | ---------: | ---------:
> 91b7521b-7298-11eb-a7c5-1f5a66f289d6 | 2020-12-02 |        0.1 |        0.2 |        0.3 |        0.4
> 91b752ed-7298-11eb-a7c5-1f5a66f289d6 | 2020-12-03 |        0.5 |        0.6 |        0.7 |        0.8
>
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=cb0afdec155608c860192b3b41b70596)*

Comment: Will this work for "hundreds of detector and unit numbers"?

Comment: Yes it wiill work and you  can program a loop taht creates the query

Comment: of course mysql has some limitations but hundr4ets of detectors is no problems thousamds yes as mysql supports only 4096 columns

Comment: The answer is probably good. However, running this for 2 columns I had to stop it after 1hour 45 minutes, it seemed like it wouldn't really get there. At this point, for hundreds of columns, I should do it manually, won't it take the same time...

Comment: for how many rows. Bulk inserts take always time, there is at the mysql site a very good article for bulk inserts wuith many insights

Comment: OK this is weird, for 1 column it took 4 minutes. I guess the scalability isn't linear then. I'll just run the query hundreds of time for different rows and I should get there in less than  a day. But now that a UUID and timestamp already has been set, the query will have to be different.

Comment: yes, you must find the joing part yourself, for that you only have the data and must see the pattern

Comment: I'll accept this, but be aware that there is a scalability issue (time-consuming) for very large datasets

Comment: Sorry to say that this technique did not work. MariaDB only allows for 61 joints or less in 1 query, which makes this answer unfortunately not the right choice. Also, I tried running it with 60 JOINTS and it has been running for now 24hours. So I really wouldn't recommend JOINTS for scalability reasons.

Comment: @PyThagoras you can try my other approach, if this also doesn't work, you have to do the pivoting in aniother language that has less  limitatations. Also group_concat_max_len is set the the max of a 32 buit system, today is evrything 64c bit, so you can incease that number

Answer (score 0):

This is de-normalizing data. Looks like a simple CROSSTAB.

Consider:

```
TRANSFORM First(Table1.value) AS FirstOfvalue
SELECT Table1.timestamp
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.timestamp
PIVOT "detector " & [unit] & [detector];
```

If you want to make sure fields are in numerical order, something like:
`PIVOT "detector " & Format([unit], "000") & Format([detector], "000");`

Use that query as source for SELECT INTO.
`SELECT *.Query1 INTO Test FROM Query1`
The unique identifier field will have to be added afterward. Or just export query instead of saving to table.

No idea how performance will be affected by "millions" of rows.

Apparently MySQL table is limited to 4096 fields. Hopefully your output will not exceed that.

Well, did some research which indicates PIVOT is not available in MySQL and will have to program a loop that builds query. Sorry! PIVOT works in Access, SQLServer, Oracle.

Comment: I want to try your approach first because it doesn't require a 200 lines query. Is PIVOT supposed to be a command or is this just conceptual code? Can't seem to find "PIVOT" I suppose it was pseudocode, I'll try to read on pivots.

Comment: It's an actual query that works in Access and SQLServer. Sorry, looks like not available in MySQL and will have to do what nbk said "program a loop taht creates the query". Review https://codingsight.com/pivot-tables-in-mysql/. I should probably delete answer.

Comment: Don't delete it. Might be useful for those who use SQL Server